# How to use GC_malloc and then call the constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

I am using the Boehm Garbage Collection in C++. How to call the constructor after allocation using GC_malloc?

```
SomeClass *i = new SomeClass(); // Here the constructor is called.
SomeClass *j = (SomeClass *)GC_malloc(sizeof(SomeClass)); // How to call the constructor here?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to perform a placement new.

```
SomeClass *j = (SomeClass *)GC_malloc(sizeof(SomeClass));
new (j) SomeClass();
```

This assumes the allocator has returned appropriately aligned memory.

Using a garbage collector with C++ can be error-prone, since the memory sweeping step is unlikely to  call the destructors of the objects to which the memory use to belong. Safer would be to use a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

In `SomeClass` overload the `operator new` this way:

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    return GC_malloc(size);
}
```

Now you can invoke any overload of the constructor of `SomeClass` with the `operator new` and the function `GC_malloc` will be invoked to allocate the memory of the new instance of `SomeClass`.

You can also in `SomeClass` overload the `operator delete` this way:

```
void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    assert(0);
}
```

And optionally, before the `assert(0);`, invoke a cross platform method that displays to the user a proper error text message that says that `SomeClass*` or any pointer to `SomeClass` instance in general should not be operand of the `delete operator`, because all the instances of `SomeClass` that were created by the `new operator` are managed by the Boehm Garbage Collector.